# css-After. How to hide the last pseudo element

Tags: css

I have a footer that has a `<ul>` with 6 `<li>`

```css
body {background:#bbb;}

.main-footer a::after {
  content: " | ";
  color: white;
  margin: 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">quienes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">servicios</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sucursales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

I need to remove the last " | " but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2):

Use `li:not(:last-child)`.

```css
body {background:#bbb;}

.main-footer li:not(:last-child) a::after {
  content: " | ";
  color: white;
  margin: 0 25%;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">quienes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">servicios</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sucursales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add below **CSS** will resolve your issue. Thanks

```
.main-footer li:last-child a::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```css
body {background:#bbb;}

.main-footer a::after {
  content: " | ";
  color: white;
  margin: 0 25%;
}

.main-footer li:last-child a::after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<footer class="main-footer">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">quienes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">servicios</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sucursales</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">contacto</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
.main-footer li:last-of-type a::after {
   display: none;
}
```

You essentially just need to target the `li:last-of-type a`, and hide their psuedo element.

Comment: @MrLister Thank you for making me look at OP's code closer. I've updated my answer to target `li:last-of-type` instead

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.main-footer li:last-of-type a::after {
  display: none;
}
```